# linking issue with assembly language program

Tags: assembly

I have a linking issue with assembly language program

```
.386
.model flat, c
.stack 100h
printf PROTO arg1:Ptr Byte
.data
msg1 byte "Hello World!",0Ah,0
.code
main proc
INVOKE printf, ADDR msg1
ret
main endp
end
```

this program is assembled with

```
ml -c -Zi "-Fl$(IntDir)\$(InputName).lst" "-Fo$(IntDir)\$(InputName).obj" "$(InputPath)"
```

it successfully generates `.obj` and `.lst` file.

i dont know how to link it to produce an **`exe`** file.

i am using vs2015 portable.

Comment: What happens when you press CTRL-F5 inside of vs2015? What happens when you omit the `-c` option in the command line?

Comment: Are you trying to make a normal 32 or 64-bit executable?  Or a DOS 16-bit executable?  Are you sure you need `.stack 100h` and the other directives at the top?  And if DOS, what C library are you trying to link against?

Comment: the software is portable, so no cltrl-f5, i am trying to make 32 bit executable. it is saying unresolved external _printf.